# Outlook Entity Detection fails to find items in forwarded messages

Tags: outlook, office-js

In our add-in we're using Entity Detection to grab phone numbers out of the email body. In most cases this works fine, however, on the Outlook Web client, it is not possible to pull these entities out of a forwarded message.

To clarify, I took these steps:
 - Added a phone number to an email
 - Sent it to myself
 - Opened the item in the read pane
 - Opened the add-in
 - Phone number is detected, same on both web and native.
[image: Detected Numbers]

Next, I forwarded the same message, on opening this message and the add-in there, Web based outlook detects no entities, while native outlook does.
[image: Failed detection]

In the attached screenshots you can also see that address and meeting suggestion entities also suffer from this detection issue.

The method in use here is `item.getEntitiesByType(Office.MailboxEnums.EntityType.PhoneNumber);` however, `getEntities()` also returns only empty arrays.

If there's something we're missing here, we'd love to know of it, but this feels like a bug.
If possible we would rather use the built in entity detection and not have to rely on  adding our own.

Comment: Just to clarify, you _are_ able to pull these numbers out of a forwarded message on Outlook 2016 for Windows/Mac?

Comment: On Windows, an unqualified yes. On Mac, when a message is not part of a conversation (no sub items/drop down) then yes. If it is, then no it does not work.

Comment: Just kidding. Outlook on Windows is now behaving the same way as Mac described above

Comment: Just to clarify, does your outlook now behave like OWA? You can't see the entities on the forwarded message but can on original message for both -
 Outlook on windows and OWA? If you switch to item view in both Outlook and OWA are you able to get the entities on the forwarded message?

Comment: There are actually two contexts in play with differing levels of functionality. I'll clarify them here.

A: An email forwarded to you with no prior conversational context (i.e. it's the first entry in the thread, so far as you're included).
B: An email forwarded to you with prior conversational context. (i.e. you have prior entries in this thread, and the items can be grouped together)

Neither of these scenarios work in OWA. Scenario A works in the native clients, while B does not.

Comment: If I understand this correctly - For A - An email had entities stamped, they forwarded the email to you (first entry in your inbox), in OWA you do not get any entities, but in outlook client you do?

Comment: Yes that is the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Both the scenarios described above work for me in native client. The difference in behavior is by design of conversational views in both clients. Switching OWA to messages view(or poping out item in a new window) will give you the entities. The getentities works on the selected item-For OWA in conversational view, the UI shows previous messages as individual items(you can click on each of those messages separately in the reading pane) and the most recent item does not have the property stamped(since its body does not contain the entity). In native client the UI represents a single item only with the body from all previous messages involved which is why you can get to the entities property. Switching OWA to messages view shall render the reading pane similar to native client and you can get to entities again.

Comment: The answer does not cover scenario B mentioned in the comments above. In that case, there is no conversational entity to click on outside of the forwarded item. To clarify further: User A sends an email with a phone number to User A or B. User A or B forwards this message to User C. User C opens the add-in, no phone numbers are found, though it shows plainly in the text. This can only look like a bug to a user.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  Learning about the new requirements add-in developers have helps us continue to enable great scenarios on our platform.  We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user voice page. Please add your request here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins. 

Thanks again for your feedback,
Outlook Engineering Team